# MarkLogic word search in whole database ( element + attributes). Looking some extended alternative to cts:word-query?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

I want to search documents containing a particular word in whole MarkLogic database (across elements and attributes). `cts:word-query` works only on elements. How can I achieve that in MarkLogic?

**Example:**

Document 1. `<abc>Data correction query</abc>`

Document 2. `<element2 state="correction"></element2>`

**Output**- If search is for word "correction" then both the above docs/URIS should be returned.

Set of possible elements-attributes containing that word is not fixed as it's a data correction exercise. Is there any possible way of extending this **`cts:word-query`** like search beyond element without knowing the attributes names?

Answer (score 4):

Attributes are not included in the universal index, so you can't just use a standard `cts:word-query`.

You could create a [field index](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields) with an XPath for the attributes you want to target and word search options enabled. Depending upon the size of your database, it might not be a great idea to use a super-generic XPath like `//*/@*`, but it is possible.

Assuming you created a field called `attr` then you could search with a [`cts:field-word-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:field-word-query) like this:

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:or-query((
    cts:word-query("correction"), 
    cts:field-word-query("attr", "correction")
  ))
)
```

Comment: Thanks! using super generic XPath is a brilliant trick (couldn't think of it) but unfortunately, can't afford this on production. 
It's kind of odd that MarkLogic creates universal indexes even on a text document words but not on attribute values. Would love to see this in future.

So, as of now, we will clear data anomalies collection wise. It will be a slow iterative process.